# サイトにアクセスしてきたユーザーの画面解像度を調べる方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx

サイトにアクセスしてきたユーザーの画面解像度を取得する方法を教えてください。

確認くんのようにブラウザの解像度と画面の解像度両方とれると嬉しいです。

確認くん
http://www.ugtop.com/spill.shtml

Comment: 「確認くん」と言うのは何らかのWebサービスのことでしょうか? だとしたら、少なくともリンクを掲載していただいた方が良いでしょう。サイト自体は知らなくても、有用なアドバイスができる方々は沢山おられます。またWebサービスでしたら、そのソースを参照されればヒントになる事柄が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

OOPerさんも指摘されていますが、質問するまでもなく当該ソースを見るだけではありませんか？

画面の解像度の取得部分

```html
<span id="ossize"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window_load();
    screen.width = window_load;
    function window_load() {
        var sW,sH,s;
        sW = screen.width;
        sH = screen.height;
        s = sW + " x " + sH+ "pix ";
        document.getElementById("ossize").innerHTML = s;
    }
</script>
```

ブラウザーの解像度の取得部分

```html
<span id="bsize"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window_load();
    window.onresize = window_load;
    function window_load() {
        var sW,sH,s;
        sW = window.innerWidth;
        sH = window.innerHeight;
        s = sW + " x " + sH+ "pix ";
        document.getElementById("bsize").innerHTML = s;
    }
</script>
```

なお、見てわかる通り、JavScriptを使用してブラウザー上で取得する必要があるため、得られた値をWebサーバーに送信する処理を作り込む必要があります。